# How to organize EmberJS nested resources?

Tags: resources, ember.js, routes

I'm trying to create a small EmberJS application, but I'm struggling about how to architecture it correctly. I have a main view called "library" which displays on a sidebar a list of folders. User can click on each folder and display the content at the center (while the sidebar is still active).

I therefore have a library resource, and nested resources to display the folders in this specific context:

```
this.resource('library', function() {
    this.resource('libraryFolders', {path: 'folders'}, function() {
        this.resource('libraryFolder', {path: ':folder_id'};
    }
};
```

To be able to access the folders in the parent root, I set up a dependency:

```
App.LibraryController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ["libraryFolders"],

  folders: null,
  foldersBinding: "controllers.libraryFolders"
});

App.LibraryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('controllers.libraryFolders.model', App.Folder.find());
  }
});
```

First question: is this a good way? I feel it a bit strange that a parent controller have a dependency to its children.

Now, another problem arises: what if I want to reuse folders in another context? All the methods I would write in LibraryFoldersController would be specific to this one, not really DRY. What I came up is adding a root "folders" resource, and add the dependency to this one instead:

```
this.resources('folders');

App.LibraryController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ["Folders"],

  folders: null,
  foldersBinding: "controllers.folders"
});

App.LibraryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    controller.set('controllers.folders.model', App.Folder.find());
  }
});
```

What do you think? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

IMO it looks good so far. You are using the `needs` API which is the correct (ember) way to setup dependencies between controllers.

Maybe if you find yourself writing repeating code you could consider creating a `Mixin` for a more general controller an put there your logic, that should be agnostic to the use cases it handles.

For example defined a `mixin`:

```
App.ControllerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  // "use case" agnostic logic here
});
```

You mix mixins into classes by passing them as the first arguments to `.extend`.

```
App.LibraryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.ControllerMixin, {
  // now you can use here the logic defined in your mixin
  // and add custom code as you please
});
```

Another possibility is to write a super class and then extend from it to inherit common logic:

> Snippet taken from the [docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html):

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  helloWorld: function() {
    alert("Hi, my name is " + this.get('name'));
  }
});

var tom = App.Person.create({
  name: 'Tom Dale'
});

tom.helloWorld(); // alerts "Hi, my name is Tom Dale".
```

One thing worth mentioning (though I think it's simply a typo) is: `needs: ["Folders"]` should be `needs: ["folders"],`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought about the mixin approach, this is something that I need to read a bit more. My main concern for the first approach was the fact that having a dependency to a children controller, which sounded strange to me.